# How to handle database changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-database-first

I am using Entity Framework with a database-first approach, and I made some changes to the database. I cannot see those changes in my application because I know I need to update it too. But how do I update my domain models classes in ASP.NET MVC? Please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open your edmx file and Right click on your edmx diagram and select Update model from database

[image]

2.if you need to add/refresh the existing tables,select the tables under add/refresh button and finish

save the changes and build your solution
[image]

Comment: Yes it worked but my domain classes has no changes . I added some properties and i can see it in diagram but domain classes are still without those properties.

Comment: save and build your solution